# Motherbord usb initialising boot loop

Tags: boot

I have problem with HP **500b MT motherbord**.

Booting stuck at usb initialising .

I Tried with new bios update even custom bios directly uploading on bios chip , no luck :(

Comment: Have you unplugged all USB storage devices?

Comment: All usb device are unplugged , it just stuck after memory startup check on USB Initialising evers single time ,

I replace RAM , Jumpers even battery nothing helps.

Comment: @Aoic - Try and disconnect all USB headers.  Yes I know what this means but its a problem solving step

Comment: I will try to remove power fuse for USB then I will try again ty for info